# Integrate JavaScript implicit includes to AngularJS partial views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-view, blockly

I am trying to create an AngularJS application that uses [Google Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/), using some partial views inside my application.

Attempting to set up the JS dependencies of Blockly inside Angular, I noticed that the core JS library of the Blockly framework adds dynamically dependencies (using `document.write(".....")` calls) to the HTML file that plays its main view role.

This is very problematic if I want to set the Blockly editor main view to be a partial view, as those JavaScript imports will be added to the partial view, and Angular will not include them correctly, as they will be out of the main `index.html` file.

My guess is that I should approach this one differently, but I am not sure how - being new to AngularJS. By doing some research, I found that there are some frameworks for JS module loading management such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), but again, they do not seem to have a way of such dynamic importing management.
Are there any suggestions on this? Thank you in advance.